# Defining a double pointer for a StructType using ref?

Tags: javascript, c, ref, node-ffi

I'm using a C-library to browse the network for specific hardware.
I have a struct, called `EyeTracker`, that contain some properties.

The library function is called using `EyeTracker**`.

*From header file (C code)*:

```
API Status _eyetracker_search(EyeTracker** eyetrackers, size_t eyetrackers_size, size_t* count_eyetrackers);
```

You are expected to allocate enough memory to fit x amount of trackers using the pointer (hope I'm making sense here).

My question is: how do I write the above using `javascript`, `ref` and `node-ffi`?

I've gotten so far as to be able to get info on **ONE** tracker.

**JavaScript code**

```
let eyeTracker = StructType({ ... }),
    numberOfTrackersToGet = 10;
let eyeTrackerStructPtr = (new eyeTracker()).ref(),
    eyeTrackerStructPtrPtr = eyeTrackerStructPtr.ref();
eyetracker_search(eyeTrackerStructPtrPtr, numberOfTrackersToGet);
```

I need to make space to `numberOfTrackersToGet` pointers to a pointer to Struct of EyeTracker type.

`ArrayType` does not seem to work.

Comment: This is [tag:c++]...not [tag:c] or maybe [tag:java]

Comment: I don't think Java has structs

Comment: I don't think C or C++ have `let`...

Comment: I assume it is node-ffi (calling a C lib from Node.js), so the posted code would be in javascript.

Comment: The [tag:node-ffi] tag is for the Node.js Foreign Function Interface, which suggests that the code shown may be written in JavaScript, but is attempting to call down to a C library.  It's the only tag that makes much sense — [tag:ref-struct] is a non-entity (2 questions, no followers, no tag wiki); and [tag:ref] is not relevant to C or C++ because it describes a keyword that is not a part of C or C++.

Comment: @Mats: Please rewrite the question to explain the context better.  You probably need to tag it with either JavaScript or Node.js so that people who've used those look at the question.  In raw C, it appears that you'd need to write: `TobiiProEyeTracker *tracker = 0;` and then in the function call you'd use `tobiiproeyetracker_function(…, &tracker, …);` to pass a 'pointer to pointer' to the function.  The function would then assign a value to `tracker` which would be used in subsequent calls to the TobiiEyeProTracker library.  But how that applies to FFI, I'm not at all sure.

Comment: I thought I tagged it with javascript, well it's done now. Thank u.

Comment: Now, `ref.refType(TobiiProEyeTracker)` should equal `TobiiProEyeTracker*`, right?
Then `ref.alloc(ref.refType(TobiiProEyeTracker)).ref()` should equal `TobiiProEyeTracker**`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the `function_call` works. If it expects an already allocated struct array, then it could accept just `TobiiProEyeTracker*`.

If it writes the pointer of an internally allocated array to a parameter, then it would use `TobiiProEyeTracker**` but in this case there is no reason to write

> You are expected to allocate enough memory ...

If the function requires a pre-allocated struct array you can use this:

```
var ArrayType = require('ref-array')

var intPtr = ref.refType('int');
var TobiiProEyeTracker = StructType({ ... })
var tobiiEyeTrackerStructPtr = ref.refType(TobiiProEyeTracker);
var tobiiEyeTrackerStructPtrPtr = ref.refType(tobiiEyeTrackerStructPtr);

var lib = ffi.Library('libnamehere', {
  'tobii_pro_eyetracker_search': [ 'void', [ tobiiEyeTrackerStructPtrPtr, 'int', intPtr ] ]
});

var numberOfTrackersToGet = 10
var tobiiEyeTrackerStructArray = ArrayType(TobiiProEyeTracker, numberOfTrackersToGet)
var TobiiProEyeTrackerSize = ...
var countPtr = ref.alloc('int'); // allocate a pointer to int

lib.tobii_pro_eyetracker_search(tobiiEyeTrackerStructArray.ref(), TobiiProEyeTrackerSize, countPtr);

var count = countPtr.deref();
```

Comment: I know it was a bad explanation of the problem, will try your suggestion.

Comment: Isn't ```tobiiEyeTrackerStructArray``` just a TYPE though?
Don't I need to create an instance with **length**?

Comment: if the tobii_pro_eyetracker_search function expects 3 arguments why the hell are you using just 2? And where did you read that the caller needs to allocate enough space? According to the function declaration it will write the pointer to the struct in the first parameter variable. My answer above will not work too.

Comment: showing the sample code for C would make things lot easier. First make it to work in C, then build the call with node-ffi in javascript

Comment: It works in C. The problem is the difference between C pointers and JavaScript arrays, I think.

Comment: I've figured it out, send in a Buffer then loop through it in "pointer"-size steps. Or a colleague who knows C did together with me.

Comment: Congratulations! You can post the correct answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted, so others can learn with it. This is allowed on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working, I'm sure it can be approved.

```
let EyeTracker = StructType({ ... fields are visible below })
let dummyCount = ref.alloc("int", 0),
    count = 5,
    tempArray = [],
    buff = Buffer.alloc(count * ref.ref(dummyCount).byteLength),
    pointerSize = ref.ref(dummyCount).byteLength; // byteLength should give the size of a pointer
    _eyetracker_search.async(buff, count, dummyCount, (err, status) => {
    for (let i = 0, len = buff.length; i < len; i += pointerSize) {
        let p = ref.readPointer(buff, i, EyeTracker.size),
            offset = 0,
            struct = new EyeTracker({
                uri: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, offset)),
                device_name: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, (offset += pointerSize))),
                serial_number: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, (offset += pointerSize))),
                model: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, (offset += pointerSize))),
                generation: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, (offset += pointerSize))),
                firmware_version: ref.readCString(ref.readPointer(p, (offset += pointerSize)))
           });
           tempArray.push(struct);
       }
   });
```